# Filter a list of object using koltin list

Tags: list, date, kotlin

I am trying to filter a list of object in Kotlin. The list is defined as `List<Temperature>` which contain the temperature hour after hour for the next 2 days and the Temperature Object is defined as :

```
data class CurrentlyEntity (
        var time: Long,
        var summary: String,
        var temp: Float)
```

The `time` is a timestamp, so I was able to retrieve it to convert it to a human-readable time and date. I have also been able to extract the lowest temperature using `.minBy`.

However, I am not able to filter the list to only get the temperature of today and remove any timestamp related to tomorrow.

I was hopy that something like:

```
listOfTemp.filter { it == DayOfToday }
```

can help?

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: Your `time` is not just a date, but a full timestamp.  And ‘today’ covers a range of timestamps — from midnight last night, until midnight tonight.  So you could do it as a range check.  Does that give you enough to go on?

Comment: maybe I can do some like `>=` or `<=`

Comment: Indeed — though it might be simpler to do `it.time in midnightLastNight until midnightTonight`.  You just have to figure out how to set those two values.

Comment: Depending on how you're converting to a readable time and date (say by using libraries in the ``java.time`` package) it might be worth just generating those results and asking the object what day it represents, and using that in your filter. That way your logic's all in one place (and you don't have to implement it yourself!) and it'll stay consistent if you have to start handling timezones or something. It's a tradeoff between that and more expensive computation (comparing a timestamp is way less work) - so it depends what you need, but it's an option!